# Tab characters no longer work in Delphi XE2 message dialogs - alternatives?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Using Delphi XE2 on Win 7 64 bit creating a 32 bit app...

In Delphi 6 we used the tab character within a message to create a nice looking, multi-line double-column dialog.

```
str := 'Left item:' + #9#9 + 'Right Item' + #13#10 +
       'Next left item: + #9 + 'Next Right Item' + ...

if MessageDlg(str, mtConfirmation,[mbYes,mbNo],0) = mrYES then...
```

This creates a nicely lined up list of data for the user to see without the need for a custom form just to ask this particular question. The right column is nicely aligned and makes it easy to see the data clearly.

In Delphi XE2 the tab characters (#9) embedded within the string are completely ignored and there is no white space at all. Using #32 does create a space but does not nicely line up like the tab character (#9). Am I running into some Unicode issue?

Any suggestions out there to get this formatting back other than using a custom form?

Cheers!

EDIT:

Of course, after I post a question I figure out a couple different workarounds.

First, using Application.MessageBox() does maintain the tab character spacing.

Secondly and oddly, this code below works and maintains the proper white space with the tab characters.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var AMsgDialog : TForm;
var str : string;
begin
  str := 'Left item:' + #9#9 + 'Right Item' + #13#10 +
         'Next left item:' + #9#9 + 'Next Right Item';
  AMsgDialog := CreateMessageDialog(str, mtConfirmation,[mbYes,mbNo],0);
  try
    if AMsgDialog.ShowModal = mrYES then begin
      //do something
    end;
  finally
    AMsgDialog.Release;
  end;
end;
```

Not sure why creating a message dialog this way would maintain the tab character spacing when the old way would not.

I know the same CreateMessageDialog function is hit when I call MessageDlg() so there must be something in between stripping out the tab characters. I was not able to trace into the code to find out what was stripping the tab characters.

Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending of some internals checks like the  Windows version (greater or equal than vista), the  value of the `UseLatestCommonDialogs`variable and if the current visual Style is the native windows theme. The [`MessageDlg`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg) uses the TTaskMessageDialog([TCustomTaskDialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomTaskDialog)) class which internally call the [`TaskDialogIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinApi function, This function is handled by Windows itself and as far i know there is not option to recognize the <kbd>Tab</kbd>  chars in a special way.

Otherwise when one of the above conditions doesn't match the `MessageDlg` uses the `CreateMessageDialog` function to create a dialog. This method draw the dialog itself using the VCL and WinApi calls, the text of the body is drawn using the [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `DT_EXPANDTABS` flag included which Expands tab characters.

So the only way which the [`MessageDlg`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg) function recognizes the  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  chars is when uses the `CreateMessageDialog` internally (you can force this behavior setting the value of UseLatestCommonDialogs to false).

Comment: I would have suggested simply using `Application.MessageBox` but the bad part of that is then you need `PChar(str)` instead of just `str`.

Comment: @WarrenP it has always annoyed me that `Application.MessageBox()` doesn't take `String` parameters, like other dialog functions do, handling casts internally as needed. This was a bigger hit to C++ users than Delphi users when making the transition from ANSI to Unicode.